# Popover works in iOS 8 but not iOS 7

Tags: ios, swift, uipopovercontroller

When running my app in iOS 7 I get the following error when trying to display a popover:
[UIPopoverController dealloc] reached while popover is still visible

It works fine in iOS 8.

My code to show the popup is:

```
let vc = InfoViewController()
vc.setText(txt)
vc.modalPresentationStyle = .Popover
var w=vc.width
if w<200 {
   w=200
}
vc.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(w+30,height+30)
let popRect = rect
let aPopover =  UIPopoverController(contentViewController: vc)
aPopover.presentPopoverFromRect(popRect, inView: view, permittedArrowDirections: UIPopoverArrowDirection.Any, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy way to fix this is declare your popover as a member variable of your class and using it.

```
var aPopover : UIPopoverController?
```

And in that method change the code like:

```
self.aPopover =  UIPopoverController(contentViewController: vc)
self.aPopover!.presentPopoverFromRect(popRect, inView: view, permittedArrowDirections: UIPopoverArrowDirection.Any, animated: true)
```

Comment: That worked great!  Now I'm having an issue where dismissViewController doesn't seem to work for popovers in iOS 7.  Any ideas on this problem?

Comment: @FloydResler: Can you explain about the issue ? How did you implement dismissViewController ?